# php: display key and value for each element of associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

The following php snippet will display both the key and the value of each element in an associative array $ar. However, couldn't it be done in a more elegant way, such that the key and the value pointers are advanced by the same mechanism? I still would like it to be executed in a `foreach` loop (or some other that does not depend on knowledge of the number of elements).

```
<?php
$ar = array("A" => "one", "B" => "two", "C" => "three");
foreach($ar as $a){
    echo "key: ".key($ar)." value: ".$a."\n";
    $ignore = next($ar);//separate key advancement - undesirable
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you just wanting to print out the key and value of each of the array's elements?

Comment: @Michael: I want to use the key and value both in the rest of my code, for a search routine.

  •David: Yes, the problem and answer are the same, but the other post starts with quite a lengthy code snippet that makes it harder to identify the problem than here. Maybe I can keep my post unmarked as duplicate, or what is the etiquette?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). You can use foreach with the key as well like a so:

```
$ar = array("A" => "one", "B" => "two", "C" => "three");
foreach ($ar as $key => $value) {
    print $key . ' => ' . $value . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Problem**
You are using the *foreach* loop in the form of

```
foreach($array as $element)
```

This iterates through the loop and gives the value of element at current iteration in $element

**Solution**

There is another form of *foreach* loop that is

```
foreach($array as $key => $value)
```

This iterates through the loop and gives the current key in $key variable and the corresponding value in $value variable.

**Code**

```
<?php
$ar = array("A" => "one", "B" => "two", "C" => "three");
foreach($ar as $key => $value){
    echo "key: ".$key." value: ".$value."\n";
}
?>
```